# How to convert node position into UIKit position?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

`scoreLabel` is cocos node.

```
scoreLabel.position = ccp(_dialogSprite.contentSize.width/2, _dialogSprite.contentSize.height/2 + 60);
```

Now I'm trying to convert node's position into UIKit, so UITextField will be located exactly at same position.

```
CGPoint pnt = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToUI:scoreLabel.position];
[txtField setFrame:CGRectMake(pnt.x, pnt.y, 200, 30)];
```

`txtField` is much lower and on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinate is correct, but you have to consider the origin of a UIView: A UIview is anchored at its top left corner as if it were a cocos node with its anchorPoint set to 0,1.

Comment: That's what convertToUI does. It considers coordinate base, so for iPad it will convert `0,0` cocos coordinate to `0,768` UIKit coordinate. I'm not sure how to convert more. The `x` position looks fine if I do it like `pnt.x + scoreLabel.contentSize.width / 2`. However, the `y` position is lower by some 218 points. `pnt.y-218` makes it to right position. I have no clue where that comes from.

Comment: The problem was `scale`... I had it set to 0 and I didn't know it would affect conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Changes Between Cocos2d and UI Coordinates.

```
x - same
y = height - y
```

Example:

Cocos2d winsize = (480, 320)
Node position   = ccp(100, 200)

Then UI position = (100, 320-200) //(x, height-y)

As LearnCocos2d told, Default anchor points are (0,0) in UIKit and (0.5,0.5) in cocos2d